# Forms using bootstrap validator in a dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Below is the html part of the bootstrap drop down. On submitting the button, I want to call ajax. However the below function is not getting triggered and instead form is submitted and I can see in the url the same page with query strings. If anyone can help me solve how to get the on submit triggered, that would be much appreciated.....

```
$('#form_createuserconfig').validator().on('submit', function (e){
        if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        //do error handling
        }else{
         //make ajax call
         if(transaction is ok){
           window.location.href="go to my page";
         else{
           //show error and let user try again
         }
         e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Below is the html

```
<div id="div_login_dropdown" class="dropdown pull-right" style="xborder:1px solid black;margin-top:-2.3em;margin-right:-0.1em">
        <!--  a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-target="#" role="button">Log in</a-->
    <button id="btn_login_ddown" class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" >Log in
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="ul_logtabs" class="dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1" style="margin-top:-1em;smargin-right:-0.1em;width:20em;heixght:20em">
      <li xrole="presentation">
        <div class="modal-body" style="xborder:1px solid red">
            <div class="well" style="xborder:1px solid green;margin-bottom:.1em">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tablogin" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabcreate" data-toggle="tab">Create Account</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content" xstyle="xborder:1px solid green">
                    <div class="tab-pane active in" id="tablogin">
                        <form class="form" action='' method="POST">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div id="legend">
                                    <legend class=""></legend>
                                </div>    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required tabindex="21">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required tabindex="22">
                                           <div class="help-block text-right"><a data-target="#" href="">Forgotten your password ?</a></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                     <label><input type="checkbox"> keep me logged in</label>
                                </div>                          
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>                
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabcreate">
                        <form id="form_createuserconfig" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div id="legend">
                                    <legend class=""></legend>
                                </div>                                      
                                <div id="createsection" style="display:none">
                                    <div classx="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input" placeholder="First Name" value='' required data-toggle="tooltip" title="First Name" tabindex="1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div classx="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input" placeholder="Last Name" value='' required data-toggle="tooltip" title="Last Name" tabindex="2">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email_add" id="email_add" class="form-control input" placeholder="Email Address" value='' data-error="Looks like that email address is invalid" required data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email Address" tabindex="3">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="password" name="usr_password" id="usr_password" class="form-control input" placeholder="Password" value='' data-minlength="8" required  
                                                    data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="4">
                                                    <span class="help-block" style="font-size:0.7em">Min 8 characters</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input" data-match="#usr_password" data-match-error="these don't match" required placeholder="Confirm Password" value='' data-toggle="popover" title="Confirm your password" tabindex="5">
                                                <span class="help-block" style="font-size:0.7em">numbers [#@$_!-] upper/lower cases</span>                                              
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>      
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="entity_type" id="entity_type" class="form-control input" placeholder="Type" value='' style="display:none">
                                        </div>                                                                                                  
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                         <input id="btn_createaccount" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Create Account"></input>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row" id="errordisplay" style="display:none">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            <!--  a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a-->
                                            <strong>Oops!&nbsp;</strong><label id="errorcontainer"></label>
                                        </div>                                  
                                    </div>                                                      
                                    <div id="a_alternateaccountcreationchoice" style="font-size:0.7em;margin-bottom:-3em;xborder:1px solid black" class="pull-right"><a href="#">Wrong account? Click here...</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>                                  
                </div>                              
             </div>
         </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to give the appropriate ID to the form like this:<form class="form" action='' method="POST" id="form_createuserconfig2 ">

Comment: ids are matched. still the problem exists..

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use the [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin rather than the one you are trying to use (which, I am assuming, is this one: [Bootstrap Validator plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)).

That might not be possible for your environment, so...in sticking with the existing plugin, @Octav is correct. You need to assign the form the ID you are trying to call (`id="form_createuserconfig"`).  Next, the if/else statement in your initial else statement is missing a bracket (`}`).  When that is missing, the JS throws up an error in Firebug.

Once that error is resolved, I believe you then need to put the e.preventDefault() into the secondary else clause.  Once you do that, things will work as you want.  I tried them in my environment with that validator plugin, and I believe things work as expected.  See the code below.  To test, I switched the variable from true to false.

```
$('#form_createuserconfig').validator().on('submit', function (e){
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    //do error handling
    } else {
        var isTrue =  true;
        if(isTrue){
            alert('Everything is OK');
        } else {
            //show error and let user try again
            alert('AJAX Error');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. much appreciated. Actually I put pseudo code for simplicity. In the process I had the @Octav mentioned error and bracket issues. My trouble is to get inside that event function which is the issue raised here. Instead of on>submit I used on>click and it worked. But on>submit is what I want for bootstrap validator to work. Sorry if i was not clear earlier with this. Can you throw some light on this ?

Comment: @user4826347 i am not 100% sure i follow, but in your on>click method, could you just do this:  $('#form_createuserconfig').validator('validate').  Otherwise, i am not sure it is an option with the plugin you are using.